# How to change pressed color on Android pop up menu items?

Tags: android

I have a popup menu created like this

```
var wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(activity, Resource.Style.PopupMenu);
var popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, _button);
popup.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popup_menu, popup.Menu);
```

**PopupMenu style**

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Graphite</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/popup_menu_selector</item>
</style>
```

**popup_menu_selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/popup_menu_item_pressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/popup_menu_item_pressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/popup_menu_item_pressed" />
</selector>
```

**popup_menu_item_pressed**

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="90dp">
   <solid android:color="@color/Aqua"/>
 </shape>
```

This is **not** working, pressed color remains orange :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which works fine:

```
        int themeID = MyApp.getActTheme(m_context);
        ContextThemeWrapper contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(m_context, MyApp.getAttributedStyle4Theme(m_context, themeID, R.attr.mainMenuStyle_txt ));
        MyPopupMenu popup = new MyPopupMenu(contextThemeWrapper, v);
        popup.inflate(R.menu.text_display_menu);
        popup.show();
```

**themes.xml** file:

```
        <item name="mainMenuStyle_txt">@style/DarkPopupMenuTXT</item>

<style name="DarkPopupMenuTXT" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/hometabs_back_dark</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/mmenu_text_bg_d</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#9a9dac</item>
</style>
```

**Pressed background color is defined in the @drawable/mmenu_text_bg_d :**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background_txt_menu_dark" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background_txt_menu_dark" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

**@drawable/pressed_background_txt_menu_dark :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/green" />
</shape>
```